# Create multiclass API

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm trying to create a multiclass API in Google Cloud Endpoints, following the instructions in the source code. Unfortunately `endpoints.api_server` is rejecting my classes with this error:

> SPI registered with multiple classes within one 
>     configuration (`Class1` and `Class2`). Each call to `register_spi` should 
>     only contain the methods from a single class.  Call 
>     repeatedly for multiple classes.

Comment: Can you share the code you are using to define the classes?

Comment: Why is this question marked as duplicate even if it was posted earlier than the one that has been marked as "original"?

Comment: Because there were actual answers there. This question stalled out when the OP was unresponsive to requests for more info/code snippets.

Comment: Wasn't trying to point fingers.